# How to manually add legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have data that looks like the follow:

```
test1 <- tibble(Freq=c(79,170,126),
               Seconds=1:3,
               Task = "Task1")
```

Which I plot it the following way:

```
ggplot(test1, aes(x=Seconds, y=Freq)) +
  geom_histogram(stat="identity", fill="red", alpha=0.5, width=1, color="black")+
  ylim(0,180) +
  labs(title="Task 1", x="Number of Seconds Inside Island", y = "Count")
```

But the graph produced have no legend. Ideally I would like a legend with the header "Task" and the red box named "Task 1".

How do I manually add a legend to a graph like this with the data produced above? The other solutions I have found are for different kinds of datasets it seems, or at least I have failed to make them work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly provide a column in `aes` if you want it on the legend. In this example, you just put a constant column

```r
test1$col <- "Task 1"
ggplot(test1, aes(x=Seconds, y=Freq, fill=col)) +
    geom_histogram(stat="identity", alpha=0.5, width=1, color="black")+
    ylim(0,180) +
    labs(title="Task 1", x="Number of Seconds Inside Island", y = "Count", fill = "Task")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ggtitle(label) # for the main title
xlab(label) # for the x axis label
ylab(label) # for the y axis label
labs(...) # for the main title, axis labels and legend titles